# Knockout.js and Select List Not Updating Property in Jquery Template

Tags: knockout.js

I am not sure why my dependent observable URL is not being updated on a select list change.  The iframe should update the url on the select on change event but nothing happens.  The dependent observable is being this though, but the template isn't being updated. It worked without the template with just statically defined HTML, but not I tried to create a template and the iframe doesn't update.

View

```
    @model AvatarViewModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    }
    <div data-bind='template: { name: "editableAgentTemplate", data: caseStudy.instructor }'>
    </div>
    <div data-bind='template: { name: "editableAgentTemplate", data: caseStudy.assistantInstructor }'>
    </div>
    <div data-bind='template: { name: "editableAgentTemplate", data: caseStudy.opponent }'>
    </div>
    <script id="editableAgentTemplate" type="text/html">
        <div>
        <div>
            <iframe style="width: 125px; height: 100px; border: none" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
                 data-bind="attr: { id: name, name: name, src: url }">
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <select data-bind="options: agents, optionsText: 'Title', optionsValue: 'Id', value: selectedId,">
        </select>
        <button data-bind="click: function() { caseStudy.saveAvatar(name, id) }">
            Update
        </button>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: text" />
        <button data-bind="click: function() { app.viewModel.caseStudy.speak(text, name) }">
            Speak
        </button>
    </div>
    </script>
    @section Script {
        <script src="/Scripts/app.avatars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Areas/Admin/Scripts/app.admin.casestudy.avatars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.avatars.init(@Html.Raw(@Model.Avatars.ToJson()));
            app.admin.caseStudy.init('@ApplicationAvatarType.Instructor.ToString()', '@ApplicationAvatarType.AssistantInstructor', '@ApplicationAvatarType.Opponent');
        </script>
    }
```

JS File

```
(function (app, $, undefined) {

    app.viewModel = app.viewModel || {};
    app.admin.caseStudy = app.admin.caseStudy || {};

    var controller = '/Admin/CaseStudy/Avatars';

    var urls = {
        GET_AVATARS: controller + '/GetAvatars',
        SAVE_AVATAR: controller + '/SaveAvatar'
    };

    var editableAgent = function () {
        this.id = ko.observable(0);
        this.selectedId = ko.observable(0),
        this.name = ko.observable('');
        this.text = ko.observable('');
        this.agents = ko.observableArray();
        this.url = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            console.log('url');
            if (this.selectedId())
            return '/Avatar/Avatar?assetId=' + this.selectedId();
        else {
            return '';
        }
        }, this);
    };

    app.viewModel.caseStudy = {
        instructor: ko.observable(new editableAgent()),
        assistantInstructor: ko.observable(new editableAgent()),
        opponent: ko.observable(new editableAgent()),
        agents: ko.observableArray()
    };

    app.viewModel.caseStudy.speak = function (text, type) {
        if (text().length > 0) {
            app.avatars.addAction({ AgentName: type(), Text: text(), Speech: text() });
            app.avatars.speak();
        }
    };

    app.admin.caseStudy.init = function (instructor, assistantInstructor, opponent) {

        app.viewModel.caseStudy.instructor().name(instructor);
        app.viewModel.caseStudy.assistantInstructor().name(assistantInstructor);
        app.viewModel.caseStudy.opponent().name(opponent);

        app.admin.caseStudy.getAvatars(function () {
            app.applyBindings();
        });
    };


    app.admin.caseStudy.getAvatars = function (callback) {
        var options = {
            url: urls.GET_AVATARS,
            callback: function (json) {
                if (json) {

                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.agents(json.Avatars);
                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.instructor().agents(json.Avatars);
                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.opponent().agents(json.Avatars);
                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.assistantInstructor().agents(json.Avatars);
                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.instructor().selectedId(json.Instructor.AssetId);
                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.opponent().selectedId(json.Opponent.AssetId);
                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.assistantInstructor().selectedId(json.AssistantInstructor.AssetId);
                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.instructor().id(json.Instructor.AssetId);
                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.opponent().id(json.Opponent.AssetId);
                    app.viewModel.caseStudy.assistantInstructor().id(json.AssistantInstructor.AssetId);

                    if (typeof (callback) === 'function') {
                        callback();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        app.makeRequest(options);
    };

    app.viewModel.caseStudy.saveAvatar = function (type, assetId) {
        var options = {
            url: urls.SAVE_AVATAR + '?type=' + type + '&assetId=' + assetId,
            callback: function (json) {
                if (json) {
                    alert('Saved');

                }
            }
        };

        app.makeRequest(options);
    };

})(window.app = window.app || {}, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one has all the makings of this issue here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/133

If you can force your agent ids to strings either on the server or in JavaScript (id + '' works), then you will not see the issue.

Also, it appears that based on some reorganization of the code, this is no longer an issue in 1.3.  So, you might want to try the beta out: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/

Comment: Absolutely correct.  The new beta version worked, let's hope there aren't any bugs upgrading.